# JPA 2 Criteria Query Inheritance

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class PartnerEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String externalId;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CP")
public class CompanyEntity extends PartnerEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "code", column = @Column(name = "category_code"))
    @AttributeOverride(name = "label", column = @Column(name = "category_label"))
    private CategoryEntity category;

}
```

I have 7 entities that inherited from PartnerEntity from which 4 entities contain the fiels category.

I tried the following to receive all PartnerEntity with a specific type and category:

```
public List<PartnerEntity > searchPartners(String type, String category) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<PartnerEntity > query = cb.createQuery(PartnerEntity .class);

    Root<PartnerEntity > root = query.from(PartnerEntity .class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), type));
    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("category").get("code"), category));
}
```

But i get this error:

> Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [category] on this
> ManagedType [com.xxx.PartnerEntity]

Comment: `PartnerEntity` doesn't have the field `category`, only `CompanyEntity` has that field, so you need to query that Entity directly.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS i have 7 entities that inherited from `PartnerEntity` from which 4 entities contain the fiels category. is it necessary to do a specific query for each entity ?

Comment: you could pullup the category field from CompanyEntity to PartnerEntity